# how to make a new line in a tag table (Spring MVC)?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, newline, jspx

I have troubles with putting a newLine in a  Java String sended to a .jspx file.
I have a table and in a cell i want display the content of the string received from the controller as :

|-------|
|  aaa      |
|  bbb         |
|-------|
instead i get this:
|-----------|
|aaa  bbb | 
 
|-----------|
with wrote the br tag between aaa and bbb (i have to write it here because else  this site does a newLine in my example..) 
The code in the java controller is:

```
   String a = "aaa";
   String b = "bbb";
   String cell= a +"<br/>"+ b;
   model.addAttribute("cell",cell);
```

I tried also (instead of the br tag) "\n " "\r\n" and "System.getProperty("line.separator")" without success

in the .jspx  i got:

```
 <table:table>
   <table:column id="firstCellId" property="cell">
   ...
   <table:column id="secondCellId" property="another column">//others tr cell of no importance..
    <table:column id="secondCellId" property="another column">//others tr cell of no importance..
 </table:table>
```

Is there any way to modify the cell without using the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by:

> htmlEscape="false"

in the tag table. I've removed it and now it works.

I don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing within,

```
String cell= "<pre>"+a +"<br/>"+ b+"</pre>";
```

Comment: nope unfortunatly it renders it as:  <pre>aaa <br/>bbb</pre> in the browser